# $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)||g(x)-h(x)|dx\leq (\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2} (\int_{[0,1]}|g(x)-h(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

I'm trying to prove that $(\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-h(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}\leq \int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2} + (\int_{[0,1]}|g(x)-h(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$, where $f,g,h\in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$.

Now, I have that $|f(x)-h(x)|^2\leq|f(x)-g(x)|^2+|g(x)-h(x)|^2+2|f(x)-g(x)||g(x)-h(x)|\forall x\in [0,1]$;

I need only to prove now that $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)||g(x)-h(x)|dx\leq (\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2} (\int_{[0,1]}|g(x)-h(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$
but I haven't gone very far in proving this last result so I'd appreciate any hint.

(Note: I don't know Holder's, Minkowski's or Cauchy-Schwarz's inequalities for integrals)

Comment: It looks like you'll have to prove Minkowsky...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove Minkowski's inequality for $p=2$, and have managed to reduce it to Hölders inequality for $p=2$.

Without mentioning the general proof of these inequalities, you should consider a specific case of Young's inequality: $ab \leq \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^2}{2} $ and consider how to apply this to your two functions f(x)-g(x) and g(x)-h(x).